# Can you install two apps to the same Virtual PC guest in Windows 7's "XP mode"?

Tags: windows-7

Win 7's  XP mode allows you to install an app and then run it within Virtual PC (Win XP) as if it were just another window.

Can you install multiple apps in the same virtual pc "guest"  and then have them appear  as separate, simultaneous Windows in Windows 7?

(E.g., if I have 4 apps that all need to run in Windows XP I'd like to run them all in on Virtual PC guest instead of in 4 different ones (to minimize system resource drain).

Anyone tried this?

Comment: Are you coming at this from the side of deploying Windows XP mode to your users or on your home PC?

Comment: This if for my primary work PC and possibly one other PC here at work.

Comment: Do you mean "install two apps" or "run multiple instances of the same app"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I'm doing it right now, and it's all under one VM.

When you close the last XP app open, it hibernates the VM again.